# Error in stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, types

I created a type named `detalleList` and I need to use it in a stored procedure but I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

This is `detalleList` type

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[detalleList] 
AS TABLE ([idCcompVtaD] [bigint] NULL,
          [idProducto] [bigint] NULL,
          [cantidad] [int] NULL,
          [precio] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
          [precioTotal] [decimal](18, 2) NULL)

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GrabarFactura]
    @List as dbo.detalleList readonly,
    @Fecha datetime,
    @total decimal(18,2),
    @notas varchar(200),
    @idUsuario bigint,
    @idCliente bigint,
    @new_identity INT = NULL OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO ccompvta (fecha, total, notas, idUsuario, idCliente) 
    VALUES (@Fecha, @total, @notas, @idUsuario, @idCliente);

    SET @new_identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    INSERT INTO dcompvta (idCcompVta, idProducto, cantidad, precio, precioTotal)  
        SELECT 
            (@new_identity, 
            idProducto, cantidad, precio, precioTotal) 
        FROM @list;
END
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_GrabarFactura, Line 19
>   Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de ','.

Comment: The "as" looks strange in the procedure definition.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last line you have some parenthesis too much:

```
select (@new_identity, idProducto,cantidad,precio, precioTotal) from @list;
```

Should be

```
select @new_identity, idProducto,cantidad,precio, precioTotal from @list;
```